# How to retrieve SimpleXMLElement object value with @ in key

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this returned from an eBay API. How can I access the values in `count` using PHP?

```
(
    [ack] => Success
    [version] => 1.13.0
    [timestamp] => 2020-04-13T00:01:52.128Z
    [searchResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )
...
```

I have tried the following but to no avail

`$x->searchResult->@attributes->count;`

`$x->searchResult['@attributes']->count;`

Comment: You can just use `$x->searchResult['count']` or `$x->searchResult->attributes()->count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see all attributes use

```
foreach ($xml->searchResult->attributes() as $a=>$b)
    echo "[$a] = $b <BR>";
```